# How to associate extension with custom editor in Eclipse 4

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp

I've recently moved to Eclipse 4. In eclipse 3.x to define which editor will be associated with file extension I had to define editors extension with extension associated with it. How to do that in Eclipse 4 where editor doesn't any more inherit from `EditorPart` but it's a part defined with dependency injection.

Here is the **old** version. What is best practice for defining custom editor being opened when we double click file with certain extension (ex. bcx) in Projects View?

```xml
<extension
         point="org.eclipse.ui.editors">
      <editor
            class="com.abb.pestc.cothex.ui.editors.AirToAirEditor"
            default="true"
            extensions="acx"
            icon="icons/cothexAirToAir.png"
            id="com.abb.pestc.cothex.ui.editors.AirToAirEditor"
            name="Air to Air Editor">
      </editor>
      <editor
            class="com.abb.pestc.cothex.ui.editors.BaseToAirEditor"
            default="true"
            extensions="bcx"
            icon="icons/cothexBaseToAir.png"
            id="com.abb.pestc.cothex.ui.editors.BaseToAirEditor"
            name="Base to Air Editor">
      </editor>
   </extension>
```

Comment: If you are creating a 'pure' e4 application (not using any Eclipse 3 compatibility code) then there is no built in mechanism for associating a file type with an editor.

Answer (score 0):

Interestingly, even in Kepler's sample Plugin projects, 3.* code is used:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<?eclipse version="3.4"?>
<plugin>

   <extension
         point="org.eclipse.ui.editors">
      <editor
            name="Sample XML Editor"
            extensions="xml"
            icon="icons/sample.gif"
            contributorClass="org.eclipse.ui.texteditor.BasicTextEditorActionContributor"
            class="tempse.editors.XMLEditor"
            id="tempse.editors.XMLEditor">
      </editor>
   </extension>

</plugin>
```

So I suspect the answer is 'same way you did it before'. I've just moved a custom editor project from 3.* to 4.* without having to make any changes at that end (and for reverse compatibility reasons I'm fairly sure I wouldn't want to).